# Use 2 files from 2 different folders stored in a listbox tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tk-toolkit

I have a code which I am trying to open different files from different folders and use those files to plot a graph. I am using askdirectory in tkinter and storing the filenames into a listbox.

`

```
        def ask():
            global path
            path = filedialog.askdirectory() # select directory 
            statusbar1.config(text=path) # update the text of Label with directory path 
            x=next(os.walk(path))[2] # list of files 
                                       
            for each_item in range(len(x)):          
                listb.insert(tk.END, x[each_item])
                listb.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "#8c92ac",fg= "#161327")
```

`
Then I want to choose a filename from the listbox and use the content to plot a graph.

`

```
        def paths_selected():
            global path
            filenames = [listb.get(i) for i in listb.curselection()]
            # do some calculations to plot
```

`

Function "ask" is operated by a button (browse). This will populate the listbox from files from any folder everytime I click the browse button. Function "paths_selected" is operated by another button to use the files selected from the listbox and plot the graph. But I can only use files from one directory at a time. I want to be able to choose a file from a different directory and use both files to plot in the same graph. Any ideas of how to do that?

Comment: Then call `askopenfilename()` twice.

Comment: @acw1668 the listbox will populate everytime I call askdirectory(). That's not a problem. Also I need to navigate through different directories and use files from each if possible. Not essentially two files.